# Oracle forms 10g, copy multiple rows to another block

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm new to oracle forms and i have a problem. I have two multiple records blocks with same fields in the form.

I query data for one block, it gets populated .
After that i need to copy all rows to new block. One helpful guy suggested following, but it keeps me in endless loop. Can you please help me resolve this?
 :

```
declare
-- local variables; should contain all items you'd want to copy
l_empno  emp.empno%type;
l_ename  emp.ename%type;
l_job    emp.job%type;
-- l_currec will contain current row number in the first block
l_currec number := 0;
-- l_exit will be used if we're at the end of the first block
l_exit varchar2(1) := 'N';
begin
loop
  -- go to the source (first block) and the [last row you were in + 1]
  go_block('first');
  l_currec := l_currec + 1;
  go_record(l_currec);`

  -- check whether this is the last row of the first block; if so, exit the loop
  if :system.last_record = 'true' then
     l_exit := 'Y';
  end if;

  -- save current row's items
  l_empno := :first.empno;
  l_ename := :first.ename;
  l_job   := :first.job

  -- go to the second block's bottom and create a new record
  go_block('second');
  last_record;
  create_record;

  -- put stored values into the second block's items
  :second.empno := l_empno;
  :second.ename := l_ename;
  :second.job   := l_job;

  -- exit the loop if this was the last record to be copied
  exit when l_exit = 'Y';
end loop;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if :system.last_record = 'true' then
```

:system.last_record returns 'TRUE' or 'FALSE' (in uppercase), so this IF statement will never be true.  The 'true' in quotes must be 'TRUE'.